# installing npm webpack-cli causes warning that cannot be understood

Tags: webpack

I installed webpack for global mode

```
npm install webpack -g
```

and checked what the webpack version is

```
webpack -v
```

result is 4.14.0

since webpack v4 we have to use webpack-cli,

```
npm install webpack-cli -g
```

it successfully installed but below warning occurs.

> npm WARN webpack-cli@3.0.8 requires a peer of webpack@^4.x.x but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I cannot understand this warning because I have checked that webpack version is above 4.

any advice would be appreciated

Comment: it is advised to use it locally other than globally. Just ignore the warning, if anything breaks then you worry about it,.

Answer (score 0):

Link globally installed package to you project by using this command line :

```
npm link webpack
```

Comment: Please let me know if it s okey ?